# Replicating Guide @Named with Python injector module

Tags: python, dependency-injection, guice

I'm using the [injector](https://injector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module that embodies most of the [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki) API for a DI framework.

What I am trying to accomplish what Guice does with the [@Named](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations#named) binding annotation. That is to say, using the `injector.Module` to override the `configure` method and use the [Binder](https://injector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=bind#injector.Binder) to bind multiple instances of the same type, but with different names:

```
import pathlib
import injector

ConfigFile = pathlib.WindowsPath
UserFile = pathlib.WindowsPath

cfg_file = pathlib.Path.home() / 'settings.cfg'
usr_file = pathlib.Path.home() / 'user.inf'

class AppModule(injector.Module):

    def configure(self, binder):
        binder.bind(ConfigFile, to=cfg_file) # Guice uses annotatedWith here
        binder.bind(UserFile, to=usr_file) # Guice uses annotatedWith here

class App:

    @injector.inject
    def __init__(self, cfg: ConfigFile, usr: UserFile):
        self.config = cfg
        self.user = usr

app = injector.Injector(AppModule).get(App)
print(app.config, app.user) # prints the contents of `usr_file` for both
```

I thought that [Binder.multibind](https://injector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=bind#injector.Binder.multibind) my have some viability, but I've been unsuccessful in my attempts. They only solution I can devise is one in which `pathlib.Path` must be subclassed and those subclasses explicitly bound to their instances (which can be manged in the `injector.Module` using [@provider](https://injector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/terminology.html?highlight=provider#module) in conjunction with [@singleton](https://injector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scopes.html?highlight=%40singleton#singletons)).

Is there another way to accomplish this that does not resolve to sublcasses?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use Annotated from either typing_extensions (already an injector's dependency or from Python 3.9 typing). In your example above just replace

```
ConfigFile = pathlib.WindowsPath
UserFile = pathlib.WindowsPath
```

with

```
ConfigFile = Annotated[pathlib.WindowsPath, 'config']
UserFile = Annotated[pathlib.WindowsPath, 'user']
```

And it should work.

It's all possible to use typing.NewType but it probably won't play nicely with static type checkers.

Here's a full working example tested on python 3.6:

```
from injector import Injector, inject, Module, singleton, provider
from typing_extensions import Annotated

from typing import NewType, Callable

# You can use Greeting instead of Annotated[str, 'greeting'] as it's the same type
Greeting = Annotated[str, 'greeting']


class Greeter:
    @inject
    def __init__(self, greeting: Annotated[str, 'greeting']):
        self.greeting = greeting

    def greet(self):
        print(self.greeting)


class MyModule(Module):

    def configure(self, binder):
        binder.bind(Greeting, to='Howdy', scope=singleton)
        binder.bind(str, to='Hello', scope=singleton)


def main():
    injector = Injector([MyModule()])
    greeter = injector.get(Greeter)
    greeter.greet()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

There's a bit of a problem, if you don't provide a binding for `Annotated[str, 'greeting']` injector will use a default constructor which produces something, but probably not what you would expect. On the other hand it handles str just the same - happily constructs an empty string.

Tests in the conda environment with the following packages installed (injector is installed using pip):

```
# Name                    Version
injector                  0.18.4 
libffi                    3.0.9  
pip                       18.1   
python                    3.6.8  
setuptools                40.8.0 
sqlite                    3.26.0 
typing-extensions         3.7.4.3
wheel                     0.33.1 
xz                        5.2.3
```

Comment: I was unaware of this, and it appears that [PEP-593](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0593/) added it to Python 3.9, unfortunately I am using Python 3.7, but the `injector` module has access to `injector.Annotated` via `typing_extensions`. I was, in fact, using `typing.NewType` to do this, but as you surmise, a static type checker will fail.

Comment: It works for me in Python 3.6 just fine, at least for wiring itself. I import Annotated from `typing_extensions`. I didn't test it with any static type checkers though.

Comment: Can you show a full example of how you use `Annotated` here? I cannot get it to work, the `Binder.bind` throws `injector.UnknownProvider`.

Comment: I've updated the post, as the example is too long to be posted as a comment.

Comment: What version of `injector` are you using? Tested your update on Python 3.6, 3.7 and 3.9 and all return the same error I was receiving.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your success, in a conda environment using the exact same versions of `injector` and `typing-extensions`. Are you sure this is all your code? You've imported several other types/callables and not used them anywhere...

Comment: The extra imports because I've took it from a larger test. To be extra double sure I've copied the code above into a file:


    $ wc -l ta.py  # making sure there's no extra new-line at the end
    33 ta.py 
    $ md5sum ta.py 
    b961b6cfbec48a46e8272845a3540b4a  ta.py
    $ python ta.py 
    Howdy

Comment: I can say with some certainty, that this test doesn't work and I believe something in your larger test is facilitating it. The `UnknownProvider` error takes place in the [`Binder.provider_for`](https://github.com/alecthomas/injector/blob/master/injector/__init__.py#L584) method; I believe its because `_punch_through_alias` returns `typing_extensions.Annotated` rather than `str`.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for you. I've removed the rest of the .py file from that directory and have only the source above. And it works for me. In any case NewType also works for me. And if it works with NewType there's no reason why it shouldn't work with Annotated.

Comment: This does not work, as of Injector v0.21 (`injector.UnknownProvider: couldn't determine provider for typing.Annotated[str, 'greeting'] to 'Howdy'`). But there appears to be a [pull-request](https://github.com/python-injector/injector/pull/219) pending for a couple months that will add support for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flask_injector, using NewType instead of Annotated is more appropriate I think because if you have multiple strings to inject the first defined value will always be returned